# RuntimeException on widget that has a Bitmap (Android)

Tags: android, bitmap, widget, recycle, runtimeexception

my app has widgets that have an ImageView and a TextView. On the onUpdate() method of the WidgetProvider, I put a Bitmap inside the ImageView this way:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.widget_btn);
Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapManager.setColor(bitmap, red, green, blue);
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image, bitmap2);
```

setColor() method is this:

```
public synchronized static Bitmap setColor(Bitmap org, float r, float g, float b)
{
    sColorMatrix.setScale(r, g, b, 1);
    sColorPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(sColorMatrix));
    // RGB_565 is faster, but loses transparency
    Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(org.getWidth(), org.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    try{
        sColorCanvas.setBitmap(ret);
        //sColorCanvas.drawColor(Color.);
        sColorCanvas.drawBitmap(org, 0, 0, sColorPaint);
    } catch (Throwable t){

    }

    return ret;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the widget throws a RuntimeException because somebody has recycled the Bitmap, and I don't know what to do. Some suggestions?

I can attach the stacktrace if it can be useful. Thank you!

---

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@462605a8
   at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:955)
   at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1044)
   at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:323)
   at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:923)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6739)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1365)
   at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3046)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6845)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2257)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1648)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1375)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6742)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1872)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1422)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1167)
   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove all calls to `Bitmap#recycle` from your code. The garbage collector will take care of unreferenced bitmaps.

Comment: Hi, I haven't called recycle() on any part of my code, that is the curious thing... Thank you!

Comment: That's very weird. `recycle` has to be explicitly called. I don't see anything jumping out at me when I do a call hierarchy on it either.

Comment: If recycle is removed, it could potentially give rise to out of memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bitmap2 goes out of scope get GC'd then when it is time be drawn it has disappeared.

Make bitmap2 a static field. This should stop it being collected until the containing class is destroyed.